# Invalid interpreter prompt even after setting up virtualenv with python3.11

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

I setup a virtual environment using "virtualenv venv --python=python3.11" then activated it with "source venv/bin/activate" and installed some dependencies using pip from a .txt file using "pip install -r /requirements.txt". I opened project in pycharm by using existing resources and selected the python existing in "venv/bin/python" as the interpretor.

When the project loads, the screenshots show what the problem is:

[image: pycharm prompt showing invalid interpretor]

[image: invalid interpretor in settings]

[image: folder structure on my machine]

[image: terminal with venv activated showing correct python versions]

I go into "configure python interpretor" and selected the python from the path "venv/bin/python". Pycharm still tells me the interpreter is invalid.

I invalidated the caches, restarted pycharm, nothing changed. Reinstalled python3.11 and pycharm, created a new venv, pip installed the dependencies from the same requirements file. Still, nothing changed. I've tried other questions on stack overflow.

Comment: If, outside of Pycharm, but inside your venv, you run `python --version`, does it indeed show 3.11?

Comment: NB: if you upload a picture, you can upload it directly to your question, instead of linking to some awkward image-generating website (awkward and generating, because the images can't be viewed as standalone).

Comment: @9769953 question edited. Yes, terminal confirms both pythons are the same, outside pycharm and in the venv as 3.11. Screenshots added to edit. For some reason, pycharm cannot see the interpretor with it's dependencies installed with pip in the venv.

Comment: Double check that the path setting in PyCharm is correct; I can't tell from the screenshots, since the path is too long to be properly included. I just tried for myself (I never use PyCharm), and initially, I saw the same warning. I had to actually go through a few steps to select an *existing* Python interpreter (in my created v-env). By default, PyCharm seems to want to make its own v-env from an existing Python (which in this case, it can't even find), which is not what you want.